# Sensitivity analysis to find out which variable has the most impact on model

Tags: r, sensitivity-analysis

I have a model which predicts contamination levels of nurses' hands after touching surfaces. It depends on 4 variables: surface contamination (V), hand contact area (A), transfer efficiency of germs ($\lambda$) and hand hygiene efficacy (h): \begin{equation}Y \sim f(\lambda, V, A,h)\end{equation}

Where:
\begin{equation} h=LN~(1.5,0.1),\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \lambda=\Gamma(15,3),\end{equation}
\begin{equation} A=LN~(7,1.9),\end{equation}
\begin{equation} V=LN~(2.5,1.9),\end{equation}

I ran a Monte Carlo simulation to produce 10000 values of Y. But I'd like to work out which of my variables has the most effect on Y. In other words I want to work out whether hand hygiene efficacy is more important than surface cleanliness.

Can Soboljansen in R deal with data input instead of the actual model? If so could you show me how please as I've not got it to so far.

Comment: Could you give some more details about the research situation and the model on which you're trying to conduct the sensitivity analysis (i.e., the contents of sobol.fun)?

Comment: Updated question: if you had an idea of a good example to work through I'd appreciate the hint. The model is run in matlab through montecarlo sampling, but I'm told R is perfect for doing the sensitivity analysis.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the `soboljansen` function, so I can't help you with specifics.  However, from the `soboljansen` help file, I assume that you specify how to handle the categorical variable through what you pass to the `model` argument.  So, if you want type of care to be represented using dummy codes and if you want to model interaction terms between care and your other variables, you would either write a function that modeled care in that way or fit a model that included those terms.  You would then pass that function / model object to `soboljansen` during your function call.

Comment: By the way, I don't see from your description how you want to represent type of care (ACTid).

Comment: @PatrickS.Forscher Thank you. care type is direct care(1), housekeeping(2), mealtimes(3), medication(4), miscellaneous (5) and personal care (6). ACTid is the type of care for each row of Y.  so eg ACTid(Y(1))=6. ie nurse 1 did personal care. Do you mean I will need to recode my entire Monte-carlo model in R? Can I not use my data files and tell R the interaction between input and output parameters is: $Y_i=A_iV_i\lambda_i-\beta_iY_{i-1}$?

Comment: I believe you would write a function that tells `soboljansen` what you would want it to do with your variables in each Monte Carlo run.  This isn't my area, so someone else would have to jump in to be more specific than that.

Comment: Is there a reason you think that [standardized/beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardized_coefficient) coefficients won't help you answer this question?

Comment: @5ayat I'd specifically like to use Sobol indices. Maybe I should rephrase the question to: Could you help me find the Sobol indices from model input and output data?

Answer (score 1):

Using your sample:

1. look at the scatterplots of Y as function of the inputs,
   it will already give you lot of information.
2. if the dependence is monotonous, calculate the spearman     correlation coefficient between Y and the inputs. The sensitivity coefficient is approximately the square of the correlation coefficient.
3. if not, you will need more complex methods, such a sobol or variance gradients.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a package you mentioned, but what you can do as well is to check "importance" of variables the same way it's done in random forests or boosted trees. Firstly, choose appropriate loss function (if your Y is continuous, one common choice is RMSE; for categorical variables you can take multiclass logloss). After that, take each variable, and check increase/decrease of your loss function after permuting it - if the loss is huge, it means that the levels of your variable are important for your prediction.